# OleDb Exception in c# “No value given for one or more required parameters.” while trying to Select Data from Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
 public DataTable opencon(PAL.property objpal)
    {
        string query = "Select UserId,Firstname,UserType from TBL_USER_LOGIN where Username=@username and Password=@password and Status=1";
        OleDbCommand objcmd = new OleDbCommand();
        objcmd.CommandText = query;
        objcmd.Connection = oldbcon;
        oldbcon.Open();
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = objpal.username;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = objpal.Password;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(objcmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Here I want to fetch some values from the table according to a condition,
but when I run this code it shows the following error:
[image]

Even though I passed the correct parameters value in @username and @password.  How can I resolve this error?  Please help.

Comment: For troubleshooting purpose, re-write the query without parameters (just hardcoded some test values) and see how it works. Depends on the results, fix either you first part (query itself), or check the parameters values. Couple other considerations: surround [Password] with angular bracket (it might be reserved word), and if Status is a Text field, then enclose '1' in single quotation marks. Rgds, Alex

Comment: Try moving `oldbcon.Open();` after parameters are added

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a test C# console application and it worked fine for me. Double-check your SQL statement to ensure that the field names you have entered exactly match the field names in the table.

Comment: @alex bell and gord Thompson
you guys are right, according to your suggestions i have recheck the code deeply and i saw  there is a wrong paramters issue in my code and i have solve it thanks buddies

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public DataTable opencon(PAL.property objpal)
{
    string query = "Select UserId,Firstname,UserType from TBL_USER_LOGIN where Username=? and Password=? and Status=1";
    OleDbCommand objcmd = new OleDbCommand();
    objcmd.CommandText = query;
    objcmd.Connection = oldbcon;
    oldbcon.Open();
    objcmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = objpal.username;
    objcmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = objpal.Password;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(objcmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

string query = "Select [UserId],[Firstname],[UserType] from [TBL_USER_LOGIN] where [Username]=? and [Password]=? and [Status]=1";