# No value given for one or more required parameters in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

May be my question marked as duplicate but I tried lots of things but didn't get rid of this error.

When I am trying to connect my c# application with Access database this exception showing. Here is my code

```
    using (var Con = Connections.Create())
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = Con;
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select Name, Id, Center, ClientCode, imgImage, SMSAPI, SenderId, SMSUserName from AdminControl where UserName= @p1 and [Password] = @p2 ";
                        Con.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtUserName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtPassword.Text);
//                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", txtUserName.Text); Tried this too
//                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", txtPassword.Text); 
                        using (OleDbDataReader LoginDr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (LoginDr.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (LoginDr.Read())
                                {
                                    // My work
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Instead of `... UserName= ? ...` try `... UserName= @p1 ...`

Comment: Also, [please don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I tried all but same problem

Comment: Please update your post with what you tried.

Comment: @mjwills I updated my post. When I execute my code Following code shows me the error  `using (OleDbDataReader LoginDr = cmd.ExecuteReader())`

Comment: Put your cmd.ExecuteReader in a try-catch statement

Comment: @KimSomers `Using` does the same

Comment: can you post the "error message" you are getting?

Comment: @Mohammad take a loot at my question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Solved Guys...`
The problem was in my query.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select Name, Id, Center, ClientCode, imgImage, SMSAPI, SenderId, SMSUserName from AdminControl where [UserName] = @p1 and [Password] = @p2;";
```

Actually `Name` is the reserve keyword for MS-Access and everytime I was executing my code it was expecting for `Name` Parameter. I just renamed that field with `FullName` and changed the same in my query too.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select FullName, Id, Center, ClientCode, imgImage, SMSAPI, SenderId, SMSUserName from AdminControl where [UserName] = @p1 and [Password] = @p2;";
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to replace ? marks with valid parameter.

```
   using (var Con = Connections.Create())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = Con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select Name, Id, Center, ClientCode, imgImage, SMSAPI, SenderId, SMSUserName from AdminControl where [UserName]= ? and [Password] = ? ";
                    Con.Open();                        
                    using (OleDbDataReader LoginDr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (LoginDr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (LoginDr.Read())
                            {
                                // My work
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still the same problem

Comment: can you please confirm userName and Password textboxes are filled with values before invoking this code?

Comment: Yes... I checked through break point. both textboxes have values.

Comment: Sorry move parameters above sql query updated my answer.

Comment: I tried your updated answer too but still the same issue.

Comment: Ok, put a break point at cmd.CommandText and get the query, figure if the query is in correct format (run the query in access).

Comment: Already did that...
Query is Okay, and getting the correct result when running the same query in database.

Comment: I suspect something goes wrong with the query try to remove parameters and directly add "UserName" and "Password" to the query, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337996/oledb-exception-in-c-sharp-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters

Comment: 01) leave command text with ? marks and update parameters with your access field name [UserName], [Password] prefixed with @ symbol this will fix your issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

Comment: Yes you are right. Wrong with my query. Check my answer. Thank you for your support.

Comment: you can mark this as answer if this really helped you (might help someone in the future)

Answer (score 0):

try this :
dont use '@' when defining parameters just this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", txtUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", txtPassword.Text);
```

and query like this :

```
where UserName= ? and Password = ?
```